# Why is Western Union so popular among scammers?

Tags: banks, scam

I've heard/read about a number of scams around the internet, and most of the time, the scammer tells the victim to transfer money using Western Union. I might be biased due to my sources, but Western Union is almost always the bank used for such transfers.

Why is Western Union so popular among scammers and how do banks avoid being used for scams as much as Western Union?

Comment: Western Union is not a bank ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Union And if you read the wiki article, you will see that they are the most widely used, most popular, and in many parts of the world, the only option for funds transfers. And they are not very strict with following anti-laundering rules ...

Comment: You are also making the assumption that WU does not want to be used for scams.

Comment: "how do banks avoid being used for scams?" -- for a start, follow anti-laundering laws, regulations and processes...

Answer (score 5):

Western Union is not just a bank, but they have a service to wire money to people that don't have an account. You just go to the office with the transfer number and a personal document and get the money.

The main difference is that once the money is sent, there's no way to reverse the transaction. If you transfer money to another bank account, you can file a criminal report and have the account frozen and maybe recover the funds. And a transfer for a bank on another country usually takes days to clear, but a Western Union wire transfer is instant, so even if the victim realizes the crime in an hour, it may be too late.